# UpdateCursor on two tables with value from SearchCursor

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2

I try to keep myself busy and learn some Python. 
I have two tables:

test2.shp (for searchcursor)

[image: 1]

test.shp (needs to be updated)

[image: 1]

I want to update `test.shp` with a `UpdateCursor`. The column which needs to be updated is `column2` if `column1` of `test.shp` satisfies a certain criteria `(column1 = aa)`.
So, `if column1 = aa`, insert value in `column2`.

I try to take the values for the update from `test2.shp` with a `SearchCursor`.

That's my code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "c:\\Users\\python_ex"

scursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("test2.shp", "column1" = 'aa', "", ["column1", "column2"], "")
ucursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("test.shp", "", "", ["column1", "column2"], "")

for srow in scursor:
    if srow == "aa":
        a = srow.getValue("column2")
    else:
        continue
        for urow in ucursor:
            if urow == "aa":
                urow.setValue("column2", a)
                cursor.updateRow(urow)
            else:
                continue
        del ucursor, urow
del urow, srow
```

I get the error: `Keyword can't be an expression` where I define the `scursor`.
But I guess that is not my only mistake...

I am working on ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2
Any ideas?

EDIT 8/7/14 12:20pm

Alright, this is what I came up with:

```
import arcpy

#set to folder where features are located
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:\\Users\\python_ex" #on windows use \\ instead of /


#---------------------------
#define variables for cursor
#---------------------------


"""SEARCHCURSOR"""
"""SearchCursor (in_table, field_names, {where_clause}, {spatial_reference}, {explode_to_points}, {sql_clause})"""
#field taken as "identifier". i.e. if column1 == a, take the value from the same row of column2
stable = "test2.shp"
sfield = ["column1", "column2"]
#where clause will be written in SQL and not assigned to variable


"""UPDATECURSOR"""
"""UpdateCursor (in_table, field_names, {where_clause}, {spatial_reference}, {explode_to_points}, {sql_clause})"""
#field taken as "identifier". i.e. if column 1 == a, take the value of the SearchCursor and insert into same row, but column2
utable = "test.shp"
ufield = ["column1", "column2"]
#where clause will be written in SQL and not assigned to variable


#--------------------------
#start the loop
#--------------------------

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(stable, sfield, """"column1" = 'aa'""") as scursor: #SQL queries in python are build that way http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001r000000
    for srow in scursor:
        print srow
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(utable, ufield, """"column1" = 'aa'""") as ucursor: #if used with statements, no need to close all the cursors
            for urow in ucursor:
                ucursor.updateRow(srow)
```

BUT, that only takes the last the last found value of `aa` in `test2.shp` and updates all the other `aa` in `test.shp` with this value!

Comment: perhaps a typo, but shouldn't UpdateCursor be capitalized?

Comment: Yep, it should be. Thanks. But that wont solve the error in the line above as I posted. I am sure it is something with this part `"test2.shp", "column1" = 'aa', "", "column1", "column2", ""`. I do not really understand how that works.

Comment: Maybe changing "column1" = 'aa' to "column1" == 'aa' will help. It looks like you are assigning a value to column1 instead of a comparison.

Comment: It says here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000064000000 that in the `WhereClause` a `SQL` statement is needed. That should work with one `=`, shouldnt it?

Comment: How do you know *which* `test2` row to use to update a given row in `test`? Do the FIDs match?

Comment: @nmpeterson That is based on the where clause. `""""column1" = 'aa'"""` column1 is the name of the column as you can see in the screen. And if that = aa, it takes the value of column2.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the 2 cursors by these lines:

```
scursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("test2.shp", """"column1" = 'aa'""", "", ["column1", "column2"], "")
ucursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("test.shp", "", "", ["column1", "column2"], "")
```

Refer to the help page [Specifying a query in Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001r000000) to build your where clause.

Then there is a problem when you write

```
if srow == "aa":
```

What exactly should be equal to "aa"? If it's `column1`, this line is not necessary since you've added a where clause to the scursor. If it's another field, you should write

```
if srow.getValue("field") == "aa":
```

Then there is a problem with the logic. 'a' is defined under the if block and you use it again under the else block. If the code jumps to else, it will not be aware of a.

Then same remark as above for `if urow == "aa":`. urow if a row, i.e. a kind of set of several fields. If you want to test if a field value for a row is 'aa', write

```
if urow.getValue("field") == "aa":
```

**EDIT:** The order of the parameters of the Search cursor is different from what is mentioned in the doc (registered as **NIM-065163** - The order of the parameters in SearchCursors is different between the Help documentation and usage). So just write

```
scursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("test2.shp", """"column1" = 'aa'""", ["column1", "column2"])
```

And your code should run just fine. It's supposed to be fixed in 10.2 but apparently it's not, so if you're not too busy, you can remind Esri to update the doc...

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your answere. Replacing my scursor with yours still gives me the same errormessage as above. Yes, I wanted to check with the `if srwo == aa` if the value of the field is `aa` and then pass it on the variable. What I understand is that I do not need that now anymore because of the `where clause`. But I still need it in my second loop to check weather the value of the column in `test.shp` is `aa` because I do not have a `where clause` in the `UpdateCursor`. I think there might be a mistake in your code. You use `""""` in `scursor`. Shouldnt that be only one `"`?

Comment: See updated answer. Don't forget to fix you logic issue with the if-else block.

Comment: Ah ok. Thats weird. On this site http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002t000000 it says something different. And that site is linked on this page: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000064000000
Anyway. Still does not work. I broke the code down into smaller peaces so see where the mistake is. I only run `scursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("test2.shp", """"column1" = 'aa'""", "", ["column1", "column2"], "")` and `for srow in scursor:
    a = srow.getValue("column2")` and `print a`. But: `Error in parsing arguments for SearchCursor`

Comment: edited my question. came up with a kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get past this first error by simplifying the way you define the search cursor. I think the whereclause expression is wrong. You wrote ...
"column1" = 'aa' and I think this whole thing needs to be in quotes.

To simplify just change that first line to

```
scursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("test2.shp")
```

because as you say you don't really need the whereclause in there (or work on getting that whereclause correct if you need it for speed).

You also cannot do

```
if srow == "aa":
```

as @GISGe points out because srow is a row and is not a value. You do it correctly on the next line so do it that way and then make the comparison. I think this will put you on the right track and refer to the documentation for the SearchCursor and UpdateCursor to keep you on track.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SearchCursor/03q300000070000000/
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/UpdateCursor/03q30000008n000000/

Comment: So the where close is correct, but the order of the parameters is not correct due to misleading documentation. Your suggestion is fine, but it's good to know this issue in case you have to use the where clause when creating the cursor.

Comment: @jbchurchill edited my question. came up with a kind of solution.